# IE won't open when running testcafe from CI

Tags: automated-tests, gitlab-ci, e2e-testing, gitlab-ci-runner, testcafe

I'm trying to run testcafe from gitlab ci using gitlab-runner ssh and/or shell on windows.
All browsers are working fine, including edge, except for ie 11.

The test freeze on the windows 10 virtual machine.

If I run the tests directly from the virtual machine or ssh, everything is working fine.

Comment: I guess this issue is more related to the `gitlab-ci-runner`. Try to create an issue in the `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` repository and provide all necessary details there.